# PyPI Repository Layout Mapping on Artifactory

Tags: python, artifactory, pypi, jfrog-mission-control

I wanted to set up a remote PyPi repository on a JFrog Artifactory. There was no repository layout mapping for PyPi on JFrog so I was facing issues with versioning of the cached packages. Could someone help me with a custom repository layout?

Comment: did you read the docs https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-RemoteRepositories ? What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Yes. But that doesn't highlight repository layouts. 
When you add a remote repository for python there is no proper folder structure. It all gets assigned to random folders based on the file name.

Comment: Here is a one of the urls used for downloading.  
https://xyz.jfrog.io/xyz/api/pypi/pypi-remote/packages/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Now based on this url the repository structure is being decided.
So the path becomes: 51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: look at https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/ There is only one accepted layout defined

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/